# Is it permissible to work for clients who want to make dating websites?

Tags: halal-haram, work, relationships, internet

I am a web developer. I have been asked by people to work on improving clients dating site design.

My question is that would it be halal for me to do it?

Comment: I guess the real question would be whether online dating sites are haram. If the purpose of online dating would be to find a wife, it might actually be safer than meeting up front to meet and talk.. and a lot more likely to get compatible personalities. You can have online flirting without any possibility of zina, because the two are physically separated. If the motive is to meet up and do.. bad things, it would be haram.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the fatwa listed below, you shouldn't work for them because of this ayah in the quran:

```
but do not help one another in sin and transgression
[al-Maa’idah 5:2]
```

Full fatwa [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/22756) about a web developer asking about making a website for selling music which is haraam, which inturn means a web developer shouldn't help them achieve their goal.  Then I guess the same principles would apply for making a dating website, as dating is haraam.

**Is dating allowed?**

> The Prophet (sws) said: “Whenever a man is alone with a woman the
>   Devil makes a third.” (Sahih Bukhari)

You can read more about dating and it's permissibility in islam [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/7492).

Comment: Dating is haram? then how are men and Women supposed to find out about one another before marrying?

Comment: oh... and when we eat and sleep we're behaving like "animals"? When you date, you don't have to sleep with one another, you can start out as possible friends.

Comment: we should be have more attention and TASLIM

Answer (score 4):

Allah Says in Suratul Isra'a Ayah 32:

> وَلَا تَقۡرَبُواْ ٱلزِّنَىٰٓ‌ۖ إِنَّهُ ۥ كَانَ فَـٰحِشَةً۬ وَسَآءَ
> سَبِيلاً۬ (٣٢)
>
> Nor come nigh to adultery: for it is a shameful (deed) and an evil, opening the road (to other evils). (32)

Zina is Haram, and in this Ayah it is clear that Allah did not say do not commit Zina, no he says do not even come close to Zina.  So not coming close to Zina means blocking everything that will get you there, the eyes which should be lowered, and the gentiles and others.  One should not date, rather he should look into marrying.  Dating can also help you get to sin Zina, so helping in that sin is and even helping to get another person in their sin is not allowed.

> وَلَا تَعَاوَنُواْ عَلَى ٱلۡإِثۡمِ وَٱلۡعُدۡوَٲنِ‌ۚ
> help ye not one another in sin and rancour

Comment: It still has the same issue as the other question in whether a dating *site* is haram. When you often sit next to a person, it may lead to temptations. But there is no physical way to zina if the person is far away. A couple can use the physical barrier to get to know each other and agree to never meet until marriage.